# How to set the battery level on Galaxy Nexus Phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know you can set the battery level on the emulator in 
android to whatever value you want from 0-100. Is there any way we can do the same for testing purposes on the Galaxy Nexus device or any Android device for that matter?

Comment: Let the battery run down to your desired level:).

Comment: Yes that's what I do now, but its a waste of time having to wait for the battery to run down.

Answer (score 4):

No these values are not changeable on your device. This is system data which can only be monitored [BatteryManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html).

Comment: What if I was ready to make changes to the AOSP code. Is there a way?